# API do WhatsApp não conecta ao banco de dados

Tags: api, docker, whatsapp

sou iniciante nessa área de servidores, docker, API do WhatsApp, etc.

Estou precisando instalar ele no meu VPS da GoDaddy. O docker já está instalado corretamente e a api do whatsapp também, instalada e rodando, como mostra o resultado do comando `docker-compose -f prod-docker-compose.yml  ps`:

```
Name                  Command               State                   Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
biz_wacore_1   /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      6250/tcp, 6251/tcp, 6252/tcp, 6253/tcp
biz_waweb_1    /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9090->443/tcp
```

E também o resultado do comando `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS            PORTS                   NAMES
3bde309754e9        docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.27.8       "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours            0.0.0.0:9090->443/tcp   biz_waweb_1
cc8371b45075        docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.27.8   "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours            6250-6253/tcp           biz_wacore_1
4110a5ed2727        mysql/mysql-server:5.7.29-1.1.15      "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours(healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp     mysql1
```

Porém quando eu executo o comando `docker-compose -f prod-docker-compose.yml logs > debug_output.txt` para colocar os erros no arquivo `debug_output.txt`, me apresenta repetidas vezes os dois problemas a seguir:

```
waweb_1   | MySQL is not up yet - sleeping
wacore_1  | MySQL is not up yet - sleeping
```

Segue meu arquivo db.env (com usuário e senha escondidos, mas estão corretos):

```
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
WA_DB_ENGINE=MYSQL
WA_DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
WA_DB_PORT=3306
WA_DB_USERNAME=***********
WA_DB_PASSWORD=***********
WA_DB_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT=180
```

Segue meu arquivo prod-docker-compose.yml:

```
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.

# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

version: '3'

volumes:
  whatsappMedia:
    driver: local

services:
  wacore:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.27.8
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    network_mode: bridge
  waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.27.8
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    ports:
     - "9090:443"
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "wacore"
    links:
      - wacore
    network_mode: bridge
```

Alguém consegue me dizer o que seria esse problema?

Aproveitando a pergunta, como eu faria para testar se está funcionando tudo ok com a API? Na documentação diz para fazer o health check, que seria uma requisição GET para `/v1/health`, mas essa URL se resumiria em `107.180.94.5:9090/v1/health`? Por que testei com essa URL no postman e deu problema ao acessar a página.

Answer (score -1):

O MySQL não está na mesma rede que os seus outros 2 containers. Se ele estivesse, você poderia se conectar a ele a partir daqueles containers através do hostname `mysql` (o próprio nome do serviço, que o docker resolve para o ip correto).

Definindo o hostname como `localhost`, você está apontando para o próprio container, e não para o container do mysql. No docker para Windows e para Mac os containers são criados com o host `host.docker.internal` apontando para o ip do host (o que resolveria no seu caso).

Infelizmente o docker não tem uma forma de especificar esse ip ainda no Linux, mas creio que na próxima versão já terá essa possibilidade, conforme você pode ver nesse pull request: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007

No momento, o que você pode fazer é obter o ip através do qual os containers do docker podem acessar o host, que pode ser obtido a partir do ip definido na rede `docker0`:

`ip route | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}'`

(essa é apenas uma das formas de obter esse ip, conforme você pode ver em https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264)

Esse ip provavelmente será `172.17.0.1` e você poderá usá-lo para definir o hostname:

`WA_DB_HOSTNAME=172.17.0.1`

Se você preferir usar `host.docker.internal` mesmo agora, você pode especificar para cada um dos seus 2 serviços:

```
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1"
```

e então:

`WA_DB_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal`

o que dará no mesmo, mas dessa forma você não precisa especificar o ip diretamente no seu arquivo de configurações, e caso o docker adicione `host.docker.internal` no Linux, será só alterar o seu arquivo `docker-compose.yml`.

É interessante obter esse ip dinamicamente, mas provavelmente defini-lo de forma estática não deverá dar problemas, pois é improvável que ele mude. De qualquer modo, creio que essa alteração resolva o problema de conexão com o MySQL que você viu nos logs.

Quanto à sua 2ª pergunta, eu não sei responder, uma vez que nunca utilizei a API do Whatsapp, e nem as imagens que você postou (`docker.whatsapp.biz/web` e `docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp`).

Comment: Quem for negativar, deixe um comentário explicando o por que. Não seja apenas um troll.

Answer (score -3):

A hospedagem de números do WhatsApp On-Premisse pode ser um tanto desafiadora e não recomendada no momento, já que o custo de hospedar e manter esses serviços acabam sendo bem elevados. Com isso, recomendo duas alternativas:

1. Você pode usar o WhatsApp Cloud API que é uma versão que o próprio WhatsApp hospeda seus números telefônicos e já permite 80 mensagens por segundo, você pode encontrar a documentação [nesse link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/).
2. Você pode usar um BSP (Business Service Provider) do WhatsApp que já possua integração direta e você já pularia essa etapa, aqui no Brasil só conheço a [Weni](https://weni.ai) que permita você usar a Cloud API de forma gratuita para até 1000 conversas no WhatsApp por mês ou até 200 pessoas atendidas no mesmo mês.